# Display unix command output in html page without any special character

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have a txt file containing output of some unix commands. Now when I open the file in dos command prompt, it display in correct format with all new lines/tabs etc. But when I open the file in html using iframe, it comes in a single line and special character in between. Is there any way in html 5 to show those special character in actual format. Means new line as new line only, rather than some special character. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to replace characters to appropriate HTML tag.

`str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');`

Comment: Thanks. But then we have to load the whole file in javascript variable and put replace for all possible special characters. Is there any other alternate to do it in one sort??

Comment: @user3913069 Can you edit your question and tell us how are you display file content in your code? Put your code in  `<pre>`  tag

Comment: I am just using iframe and set src=<url of the file>. Tried <pre> tag, but same output...:(

Comment: @user3913069 put __iframe__ tag inside of __pre__ tag. and replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.